# MariaDB v 10: console login failure

Tags: authentication, console, mariadb

I have installed MariaDB server:

```
$ mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.32-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
```

and have created new user 'alex':

```
> SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1 |
| root             | ::1       |
| alex             | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| root             | myhost    |
+------------------+-----------+
```

I can connect to the server as 'alex'@'localhost' using [DBeaver](https://dbeaver.com/) client but I cannot do the same from console:

```
$ mysql -h localhost --user=alex --password=...
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'alex'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I can connect as 'root' from console but not as 'alex'. Permissions are OK when I connected with DBeaver.

Comment: I have created new user 'alex'@'%', after that I have connected to the server from console.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 44
Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

MariaDB [(none)]> CREATE USER 'alex'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> SELECT `User`, `Host` FROM `mysql`.`user`;
+------------------+-----------+
| User             | Host      |
+------------------+-----------+
| root             | 127.0.0.1 |
| root             | ::1       |
| alex             | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost |
| root             | localhost |
| root             | myhost    |
+------------------+-----------+
6 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> exit
Bye

$ mysql -h localhost --user=alex --password
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 48
Server version: 10.0.32-MariaDB mariadb.org binary distribution

MariaDB [(none)]>
```

Comment: I can reproduce your scenario and create user 'alex2' w/o password that can connect to the server using console.

Comment: I can create new user with password too. Probably this is not MariaDB issue, this is DBeaver issue - I have created new user (alex) from DBeaver session under 'root'. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Yes, I cannot connect to MariaDB server using DBeaver CE 4.2.0 if user was created through console and I cannot connect to MariaDB server using console if user was created through DBeaver. With one exception - "root" (was created during MariaDB installation process).